Can tcp socket be bound to a current used local address?
I found the following code:
int fd1 = socket(...);
bind(fd1, "0.0.0.0:0");
connect(fd1, addr1);    // ------------ EINPROGRESS
addr = getsockname(fd1);

int fd2 = socket(...);
bind(fd2, addr);
connect(fd1, addr2);  // ------------- EINPROGRESS

send(fd1, message); // --------------> OK


All the calls are succeed, which I can't understand why a still used local address can be bound to fd2;
Is it allowed? The strace is as following:
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP) = 27
setsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(27, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
connect(27, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(21116), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.3.47")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS --------------------------- 1
getsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(27, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
getsockname(27, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(41473), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.3.47")}, [128->16]) = 0  ---------------------------- 2

socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP) = 28
setsockopt(28, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(28, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(28, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(41473), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.3.47")}, 16) = 0    ----------------------------------------- 3
connect(28, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(21117), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.3.47")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS  --------------------------  4
getsockopt(28, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(28, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
getsockname(28, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(41473), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.3.47")}, [128->16]) = 0

epoll_ctl(12, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 28, NULL) = 0
fcntl(28, F_GETFD)         = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(28) = 0
sendto(27, "\304R/\n\v\236\332\346wXif\311_\375\1\22\t426463026\32\f192"..., 50, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 50    ------------------------------- 5


The address 0.0.0.0 is the same as INADDR_ANY, which is a wildcard address that binds to all interfaces. You can have multiple sockets bound to that address, as long as you're using different ports.

strace() shows calls to setsockopt() that aren't in the code you posted. SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT allow reusing the same address and port.

what I mean is getting the real bound addrtess for fd1 via getsockname; then bound fd2 to it while fd1 is still alive --- no close/shutdown --- then connect(fd2) is OK, no reporting the address is used by fd1;  and fd1 can be used to sent data at last.   setsockopt does not matter here.

@user2256177 A TCP connection is uniquely identified by the tuple of {protocol, localIP, localPort, remoteIP, remotePort}. So, two TCP sockets can be bound to the same local IP/port as long as they are connected to different remote IPs/ports. And likewise, 2 TCP sockets can be connected to the same remote IP/port if they are bound to different local IPs/ports.

It is allowed. Similar approach is commonly used in server side. For example: When a HTTPS server on IP 11.22.33.44 accepts several TCP connections, all the TCP sockets will have local address: 11.22.33.44:443.
